# white line in PNG images in Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, png, assets

I am currently making a simple game, but my assets even though they are png and there are no lines or anything with them before I export them, they keep having white lines when I put them in Unity.

[The dialog box with white lines in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1kr6.png)

[This is the dialog box when viewed from the png file or from the resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltG7c.png)

There is also one image tho it does not have any white line, it does have white edges in Unity

[The phone asset in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSqMe.png)

[This is the phone when viewed from the file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd4DD.png)

Here are the import settings of both of the image

[dialog box import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTjFf.png)

[phone image import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jzSs.png)

What should I do to fix this in Unity?

Comment: Try and disable the "Generate Physics Shape" from your png import settings and see if it does any change.

Comment: Sorry it did nothing. but apparently if I change either wrap mode or filter mode. the white lines or edges disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by tweaking either the Wrap Mode or the Filter Mode.

In the dialog box or in the case of the white lines, when I change the wrap mode to `Clamp`, `Mirror`, or `Mirror once`, the line disappears as well as when changing the filter mode to `Point(No filter)`.

In case of the white edges, Wrap Mode has no effect on it, it can only be removed when setting the Filter Mode to `Point(No filter)`.